# Why the custom exception message from an exception is not shown in a Xamarin solution?

Tags: exception, xamarin, visual-studio-2017

I have been understanding this example for Xamarin cross-platform mobile development:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn879698.aspx

I made an error by copying two times the the API key in the code:

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace XWeatherApp
{
    public class Core
    {
        public static async Task<Weather> GetWeather(string zipCode)
        {
            //Sign up for a free API key at http://openweathermap.org/appid  
            string key = "40aabb59f41e9e88db7be4bab11f49f8";
            string queryString = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?zip="
                + zipCode + ",us&appid=" + key + "&units=imperial";

            //Make sure developers running this sample replaced the API key
            if (key == "40aabb59f41e9e88db7be4bab11f49f8")
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("You must obtain an API key from openweathermap.org/appid and save it in the 'key' variable.");
            }

            dynamic results = await DataService.getDataFromService(queryString).ConfigureAwait(true);

            if (results["weather"] != null)
            {
                Weather weather = new Weather();
                weather.Title = (string)results["name"];
                weather.Temperature = (string)results["main"]["temp"] + " F";
                weather.Wind = (string)results["wind"]["speed"] + " mph";
                weather.Humidity = (string)results["main"]["humidity"] + " %";
                weather.Visibility = (string)results["weather"][0]["main"];

                DateTime time = new System.DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0);
                DateTime sunrise = time.AddSeconds((double)results["sys"]["sunrise"]);
                DateTime sunset = time.AddSeconds((double)results["sys"]["sunset"]);
                weather.Sunrise = sunrise.ToString() + " UTC";
                weather.Sunset = sunset.ToString() + " UTC";
                return weather;
            }
            else
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Specifically, in the lines after the two comments.

I deployed the app to a physical Android phone. Obviously I got an exception (this was not so obvious after some minutes looking for the failing code).

That exception wasn't displayed in the Output window (in Visual Studio 2017). I just only got this message on screen:

[image: Unhandled exception]

Why don't the custom message for the exception (i.e., *You must obtain an API key from openweathermap.org/appid and save it in the 'key' variable.*).

Comment: unless you do try/catch and print the exception on the catch section, the exception message is displayed on the debug output window.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use a try/catch?

something like

```
try{
    await GetWeather(string zipCode);
}
catch(Exception ex) {
    // here you should have your exception
}
```